# send select option data to node js server in angular 8

Tags: angular8

I want to send select option data to node js server in angular
Here is my html

```
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="select1">Zone</label>
              <select #zone class="form-control" id="select1">
                <option disabled="disabled">Select Zone</option>
                <option >zone-1</option>
                <option>zone-2</option>
                <option >zone-3</option>
                <option >zone-4</option>
                <option >zone-5</option>
                <option >zone-6</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="get-btn1">
              <a  (click)="analyticDataSend(zone.value)" class="btn btn-success">Start</a>
            </div>
```

Here is my ts code

```
         analyticDataSend(zone: string) {    

          this.http.post('http://localhost:8012/sendmail', zone).subscribe();
          console.log(zone)
           }
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send string in post request, It has to be a json object. as shown below:

```
analyticDataSend(zone: string) {        
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8012/sendmail', {'zoneName':zone}).subscribe();
    console.log(zone)
 }
```